# ASP.NET MVC Button Action Result to view next data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a button that with an action result of BtnNext, Can someone teach me how whenever I click this button it shows me the next data in my Queue Entity 
in the samepage.

```
<button class="Middle-next dim btn-large-dim" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("BtnNext","TellerScreens")'">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
    <span>Next</span>
</button>
```

Comment: what you mean "same page"?

Comment: @daremachine Probably OP means "without reloading entire view page", in other words OP may looking for AJAX.

Comment: just in that same page that i display the data of my database.
just when i click the next button i want the displayed data to be replace by the next data in view

Comment: basically just click next button then display the next data in the database, but not going to other page

Comment: this is what you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax